# how can I set HTML body's first table's first'row first's td's height using Jquery?

Tags: jquery

how can I set HTML body's first table's first'row first's td's height using Jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$('body table:first tr:first td:first').height(500);

Comment: overkill.. as i stated in my answer below $("td:first") will get the first td of the first tr of the first table on a page.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the meaning of your question..

To get the first td on the page (which will be the first td of the first tr of the first table).

```
$("td:first").css("height", "65");
```

but if you want to set the height of all the td's of the first tr

```
$("tr:first td").each(function(index)
     $(this).css("height", "65");
});
```

But modifying the height of one cell will mean all the other cells are of that set height anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
$("table:first tr:eq(0) td:first-child").css("height","300");
```

But there is one more thing: if you modify a cell height, all the others from the same row will follow.

Answer (score -1):

```
$($($($('body').first('table')).first('tr')).first('td')).height(500);
```

Comment: Why god why?? Were you intentionally trying to be confusing?

Comment: lol im not trying to be confusing.  it selects exactly what was asked